# How to save data from a ModelForm?

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I am new to Django, so I am trying to build a dummy site which contains most of the basic concepts, but when it comes to saving data from a form, I am really struggling.

I have watched many videos and following tutorials everything works fine, but they all use different methods with class-based views and all. All I am trying to do is saving some data from a form following the Django documentation.

The project at this stage is very simple: a homepage with a dropdown menu inside the navbar labelled 'Person'. From the dropdown, the user can select two links, and namely 'Persons List', and 'Create Person'.

Now, I am using function-based views as you can see from views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person
from .forms import CreatePersonForm
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def persons_list_view(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    context = {
        'persons': persons
    }
    return render(request, 'persons_list.html', context)


def create_person_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePersonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponse('Working!')
    else:
        form = CreatePersonForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'create_person.html', context)
```

From these functions, I am deriving the form to create an instance of the Person class, so I am using the `ModelForm` class, as shown in forms.py.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Person


class CreatePersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            # 'adult',
            # 'date_of_birth',
            # 'high_in_meters',
            # 'age',
            # 'email',
            # 'portrait',
            # 'number_of_cars_owned',
            # 'smartphone',
            # 'smartphone',
            # 'pets',
            # 'national_insurance_number',
            # 'balance',
        ]
```

And my models.py looks as follow (most of the class attributes are commented out just because I don't want to have some validation errors).

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator


# Create your models here.
class Smartphone(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Apple')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Iphone X')


class Pet(models.Model):
    species = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Cat')


class NationalInsuranceNumber(models.Model):
    alphanumerical_value = models.CharField(max_length=9, default='ABC15VFT')


class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # adult = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=None)
    # created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    # updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    # high_in_meters = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    # age = models.DurationField(default=None)
    # email = models.EmailField(default='email@example.com')
    # portrait = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    # number_of_cars_owned = models.IntegerField(default=None, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)])
    # smartphone = models.ForeignKey('Smartphone', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    # pets = models.ManyToManyField('Pet', blank=True)
    # national_insurance_number = models.OneToOneField('NationalInsuranceNumber',
    #                                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    #                                                  default=None,
    #                                                  null=True, blank=True)
    # balance = models.IntegerField(default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Lastly, here is my create_person.html template which works fine

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}}

{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mt-4 ">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display ml-5 -4 mt-4 " align="center">Create Person</h1>
        <div class="container mt-3 mb-3">
            <div class="mt-5 ml-5">
                <form action="/person/persons-list/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Create Person">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this in order to make the form actually saving data?
I'd rather stick on function-based views and model forms if possible, and than from that basis face forms. Form and class-based views.

This is what I get in the terminal when running the server and:

1. From the Homepage dropdown list clicking on Create person
2. Filling the form with values 'John ' and 'Smith'
3. clicking on the 'Create Person' button.

It takes me to the persons-list page, as wanted, but no person is created and therefore displayed in the list. (the list page works fine if I create persons with the admin page)

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 29, 2019 - 08:25:39
Django version 2.2.7, using settings 'my_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[29/Nov/2019 08:25:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2703
[29/Nov/2019 08:25:48] "GET /person/create-person/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3145
[29/Nov/2019 08:25:53] "POST /person/persons-list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2581
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in form action you have written `action="/person/persons-list/"`, so when you submit the form, it goes to `/person/persons-list/` it does not hit `create_person_view` view. So change it to `action="/person/create/"`(or the url for person create view).

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! I have been all day on it yesterday...should have asked before